# Android Studio / Gradle - Building two applications from common code

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I'm fairly new to the Gradle build system so I'm wondering how I can handle this task. I am looking to build two separate Android applications that depend on a common set of code. How can I structure this with Android Studio and Gradle?

My first inclination is to build three modules: two Android application modules, and one Android library module (which houses the common code). The two Android application modules would have a dependency on the library module. Is this the best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: no the right forum to ask such questions, but it sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how different the applications are. If you are looking to merely change resources such as images, colors, or strings for branding purposes then you are better off having one module with [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors).

The official documentation states that if the answer to "Is this the same application?" is yes, then flavors is the way to go.

If the applications are different enough such that they won't share any resources then your approach makes sense.